# swift удаление элемента из массива

Tags: xcode, swift

Есть массив, который определен классом, т.е. состоит из переменных, в которых содержится текст типа `String` и изображение `UIImage`.

Далее, по нажатию кнопки нужно узнать, есть ли эта переменная в массиве, например, с определенным именем, и если есть, то тогда удалить его из массива.

Выглядит примерно так:

```
class QuestSub: NSObject, NSCoding{

var name: String
var image: UIImage

init(name:String, image:UIImage) {
    self.name = name
    self.image = image

}
```

И eсть массив:

```
var questSubArray: [QuestSub] = []
```

Далее, есть переменные определенных объектов:

```
let key = (QuestSub(name: "Ключик", image: UIImage(named: "ключ")!))
```

Которые добавляем в массив:

```
questSubArray.append(key)
```

И вот нужно узнать, если этот `key` в массиве, и если есть то удалить его.

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так, если такой объект заведомо один:

```
 if questSubArray.contains(key){
 let removed = questSubArray.remove(at: questSubArray.firstIndex(of element: key))
 }
```

или вот так, если таких объектов может быть несколько:

```
if questSubArray.contains(key){questSubArray.removeAll(where:{ key == $0 })}
```

Comment: при проверке элемента выдает false, хотя он добавляется при нажатии кнопки. Не знаю в чем дело

Comment: тогда надо писать функцию для класса, которая будет сравнивать 2 объекта этого класса и фильтровать через нее весь массив, получать элемент и удалять его.

Comment: можно чутка поподробнее?)

Comment: добавил еще один ответ

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй добавить такую функцию в класс:

```
class QuestSub: NSObject, NSCoding{

var name: String
var image: UIImage

init(name:String, image:UIImage) {
    self.name = name
    self.image = image

func isObjectEqual (to object: QuestSub) -> (Bool) {
    let data1: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.image)!
    let data2: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(object.image)!

    return data1.isEqual(data2) && self.name.isEqual(object.name)
   }
}
```

вот так удаляем из массива:

```
questSubArray.removeAll(where:{ $0.isObjectEqual(to: key) })
```

Comment: ругается на &
    Unexpected non-void return value in void function

Comment: сорри, забыл... поправил

Comment: строка с удалением ошибку выдает Incorrect argument label in call (have 'where:', expected 'keepingCapacity:')
при замене не работает)

Comment: наверное стоило упомянуть, что класс кодируется NSCoder